# Sails js findOne() returns result despite all criteria not met

Tags: sails.js

I have a challenge here. Sails Model.findOne() is meant to search the database based on set criteria. I however cannot explain the result I am getting. I set two criteria, adminId and authToken. Both are meant to be received via http request. My adminId is set but my authToken is undefined. Yet, my returned result is one that has its authToken set. I expected an error not a valid response. Why please?

Please see code below:

```js
    ...
    const authToken = req.headers['auth-key'];
    const adminId = req.param('adminId');
    console.log("IDs", authToken);
    const sessionExist = await Session.findOne({adminId, authToken})
    console.log("session", sessionExist);
    ...
```

Meanwhile my console reads the following

```js
IDs undefined
session {
  createdAt: 1582374230905,
  updatedAt: 1582374230906,
  id: 1,
  adminId: 3,
  authToken: 'fLREaL2BS0QSQHveUo3ZECfVxFJGk7MKxVBoON94Afoj2+tYS5tow5t14/JdcMCy9x+7P6evkLsCCNw4RjPBhHR/Q0UM5hjJPA=='
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undefined value that you have mentioned is an odd case and one that Mike had covered here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/4639#issuecomment-320369193

Consider casting the undefined type to something other than undefined:

```
const authToken = req.headers['auth-key'] || null;
```

So as to avoid querying the explicit value of `undefined`.